# shower installation with pipes coming from the floor

Tags: shower

I bought a house with a strange shower installation and am trying to make the best of it.

In all bathrooms, the shower pipes come from the floor, not the wall. From the previous owners we inherited these all-in-one shower cabins standing there, and I suspect there is electricity as well nearby, which strikes me as even more odd if not unsafe.

I want to replace these shower cabins with ordinary showers. But since the pipes are not in the walls as normally, but coming from the floor, I'm trying to figure out if there is a way to bring the pipes up to the normal shower level without breaking tiles on the walls. I just don't have many replacement tiles.

Maybe there is a shower head panel that goes all the way to the floor and could hide the pipes inside? I'm ok with drilling into the wall for screws, but if possible would want to avoid breaking open the wall in order to put the pipes there.

*Update: bad pictures added*

[image: one installation]
[image: second installation]

Comment: If you could supply some pictures that would help.

Comment: I would've if it were easy. There are still shower boxes standing above them, if I crawl on the floor I can just about see what is going on. I tried a picture but if you don't already know what's on it, it doesn't show anything due to the perspective, sorry.

Comment: Really need pictures, to many variables  to give a solid answer.

Comment: I added some bad pictures. As I said, current stuff is still standing there, making it difficult to get pics.

Comment: Can you post a picture of the inside of the shower?  I was imagining the pipes running up the wall inside the shower, but everything you've shown appears to be outside the shower.

Comment: Sorry for being unclear. The pipes connect to an all-in-one shower system, similar to this: http://www.hangingbathroomvanity.com/photo/pl12212000-medium_jets_quadrant_shower_cabin_all_in_one_shower_enclosure_electronic_system.jpg -- running up the wall inside the shower is something I am thinking about in order to not open up the wall.

Comment: Guess I need photos also because pipes coming up a wall are normal, if inside the wall it may be set up for a 1 piece supply like you linked to.

Comment: But that's the point. The pipes do **not** come up the wall. They come out of the floor. In the pictures posted above, down is actually down.

Comment: So, the pipes are NOT inside the wall, correct? They are outside the wall in the open bathroom space? From the floor or wall doesn't matter as much as inside the wall or outside the wall. To install an "ordinary" shower, wouldn't you need to remove some time anyway? Or cover it with a surround....its confusing what you are asking. Need more photos of inside the shower cabin and the bathroom facing this cabin so we can get a clue of what we are really looking at.

Comment: Exactly. Pipes are **not** inside the wall. They come from the floor about 20 cm away from the wall. The rest of the bathroom is perfectly ordinary. Just the pipe installation was made apparently for a free-standing bathtub or something.